# Xtext disable validation from imported metamodel

Tags: validation, xtext

I would like to know if it is possible to disable the validation for a subset of modelelements which are specified in the metamodel.

The problem is that I'm getting some validation-errors from the Xtexteditor while writting my dsl-file. So my idea is to disable the validation for exactly this modelelement.
I try to build a real simple textual notation and want to serialize the (valid) model while saving the file. The saved model is modified during the saving process, so it is
valid at the end.

Regards,
Alex

Lets beginn with the grammer:
I'am working on an imported metamodel (UML2):

```
import "http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/4.0.0/UML"
```

Then I create all the necessary parserules to define a classdiagram. In my case the problem appears
in the parserrule for associations between classes:

```
AssociationClass_Impl returns AssociationClass:
{AssociationClass} 'assoc' name=ID'{'
(ownedAttribute+=Property_Impl)*
'}';
```

And of course the parserrule for properties:

```
Property_Impl returns Property:
     name=ID ':' type=[Type|QualifiedName]
     (association=[AssociationClass|QualifiedName])?
     ;
```

Now some words to the problem itself. While editing the xtext-file in the xtexteditor of the runtime eclipse, the build model is validated. The problem is here that the metamodel itself has several constraints for an AssociationClass (screenshot not possible yet ):

```
Multiple markers at this line
- The feature 'memberEnd' of 'org.eclipse.uml2.uml.internal.impl.AssociationClassImpl@142edebe{platform:/resource/aaa/test.mydsl#//Has}'   
  with 0 values must have at least 2 values
- The feature 'relatedElement' of 'org.eclipse.uml2.uml.internal.impl.AssociationClassImpl@142edebe{platform:/resource/aaa/test.mydsl#//Has}'  
with 0 values must have at least 1 values
- The feature 'endType' of 'org.eclipse.uml2.uml.internal.impl.AssociationClassImpl@142edebe{platform:/resource/aaa/test.mydsl#//Has}'
with 0 values must have at least 1 values
- An association has to have min. two ownedends.
```

And now I wanted to know if it is possible to disable the validation for exactly this modelelement. So I can hide the errorinformation from the user. Because I want to serialize the created xtextmodel in the next step and will do some modeltransformations.

Comment: Ok! Lets beginn with the grammer file.

Comment: does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like UML registers this validator in the global singleton registry. So you basically need to avoid using the registry. You can do that by binding a different element in your runtime modul:

```
public EValidator.Registry bindEValidatorRegistry() {
    // return an empty one as opposed to EValidator.Registry.INSTANCE
    return new org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.ValidationDelegateRegistryImpl();
}
```